# Eclipse - what's wrong with the project

Tags: eclipse

What's wrong - how can I find out what Eclipse doesn't like about my project?

[image]

As you can see it shows no errors in sources, no other errors, just the project. There is no tooltip telling me what's wrong. Can't see anything wrong on console either. Project builds fine with build.xml.
What the hell Eclipse wants from me and my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window -> Show View -> Problems (alternatively Alt Shift Q, X)

This window should show a description of the error.

It's likely some problem in the build path or one of the dependencies of your project. If a dependency cannot compile, your project will not compile too, although there is no explicit error in its code.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. The problem is somewhat strange - it says I have a loop in projects. Indeed this project references some files from another project, but there's no loop. Both project build correctly from build.xml and run fine when started manually.

Comment: The latest versions of Eclipse, from my point of view, have some bugs that do not make much sense and disappear after a clean/rebuild project. But maybe in your case your project references another one that references the first project, hence the loop. Eclipse has its own way to deal with things; take a look at the .launch file. It means that build.xml has nothing to do with it: Eclipse relies on the settings inside the launch window (Run Configuration), not on build.xml. That's why sometimes things work fine manually but not in the IDE, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

start with the [eclipse log](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/au16690_.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Any errors with the project should be shown in the Problems view (if it's not visible, choose Window → Show View → Problems).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can clean whole project first